# Is GCP Cloudsql "on-demand" backup is incremental or full?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Base on what I got from [GCP doc](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/backups) the Auto backup is incremental: "Backups for Second Generation instances are incremental; they contain only data that has changed since the previous backup was taken"

But I don't see any docs related to the "on-demand" backup. Is that the full backup(I guess so)? But I don't see any formal doc about this.

Anyone have any ideas pls!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On-demand backup is incremental as well, and is noted in the page when you click "Create backup" in the BACKUPS tab.

Comment: I see it now. Thanks Katayoon a lot.